# Configuring Java Compiler->Errors/Warnings within pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am looking for a solution for the stated problem. I already figured out, that the project-settings from "Project Properties"->"Java Compiler"->"Errors/Warnings" are going to `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` (like e.g. `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error`).

It would be great, if I could configure these settings in the projects *pom.xml*. Additionally it would be nice, to let the *maven-compiler-plugin* recognise these settings and apply them when beeing called on the command line or by a ci-tool.

Did anyone had the same problem yet?

Kind regards,
Avi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, maven would not understand eclipse compiler settings.  Another, Eclipse uses ecj by default.

maven compiler plugin can be configured with the parameters that java compiler understands.  It can take a few parameters as documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html), but doubtful if it meets the requirement you have.

Perhaps a candidate for a custom plugin?